# Is there a component for logging messages with Spring Integration using Java DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I'm using Spring Integration to develop my integration scenarios. When I have to write some logs to provide some information, I write this way:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow blacklist(BlacklistService service) {
    return m -> m
            .wireTap(f -> f.handle(t -> log.info("Adding email source address in blacklist...")))
            .<MessageHandlingException, Blacklist>transform(p -> SourceBlacklist.of((Email) p.getFailedMessage().getHeaders().get(IntegrationConstants.MailSender.EMAIL)))
            .wireTap(f -> f.handle(t -> log.info("Email source address added to blacklist.")))
            .handle(service, "voidSave");
}
```

I'm using a wiretap with lambda and handle to log my messages. Is there a better way to write log with Spring Integration using Java DSL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always can just switch on the logging for the `org.springframework.integration` category.

From other side Spring Integration suggests logging in the integration flow as an `adapter` - `<logging-channel-adapter>`. So, what you need is just send message to the channel of that adapter. From the configuration perspective that looks like:

```
<wire-tap channel="logging" pattern="*"/>

<logging-channel-adapter id="logging"/>
```

The same we can configure with Java DSL, but we should rely on the target class - `LoggingHandler`:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "logging")
@Bean
public loggingHandler() {
    return new LoggingHandler();
}

...

.transform()
.wireTap("logging")
.handle();
```

Although I can see your point and we really could add something convenient to framework directly.

Feel free to raise a GH issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues) on the matter and we continue to discuss the feature there.

But right now your solution doesn't look bad, to be honest.

**UPDATE**

The request for the Framework on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/70